# How to ignore Angular $watch event when I myself have caused it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a custom UI element with link to ngModel:

```
scope: 
{   
  ngModel        : "="
}
```

There are two ways how the attached model might change:

1. it is changed from outside - in this case I want to update UI of my custom element
2. it is changed from inside - in this case I want to ignore the changes because my UI is already up-to-date

I have a watch:

```
$scope.$watch("ngModel", function(newValue){

// here I have complex logic to traverse newValue
// to see if it matches my current UI state
// if it matches, then I return
// if it does not match, then I sync my UI to the newValue 

});
```

and I have a function which pushes current UI state to the model:

```
function pushSelectionToModel() {
    // some code
    $scope.ngModel = newState;
    // some code
}
```

Everything works fine, but in cases when user is scrolling through my UI directive fast, ngModel watch is being triggered each time. My code to detect if newValue matches my current UI state is fairly complex, thus causing performance issues.

A natural solution seems to be somehow to ignore the $watch in case when I have just called `pushSelectionToModel`. I cannot just disable the watch in `pushSelectionToModel` before update and enable after that because the watch is executed later, after `pushSelectionToModel` has exited.

**How do I tell Angular that for some particular model assignment operation I don't want to trigger some particular $watch?**

Here is the relevant simplified [Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BUxJM)

Essentially I want to prevent `updateUi()` from being called twice when I click Apply button. But the example is simplified, in reality I can't directly assign or compare `innerName` and `ngModel` values because in my actual code the values differ because of some transformations.

Comment: Read through the question twice but still have a hard time imagining what's going on. Could you include a fiddle?

Comment: You should override the ngModelController.$render method instead of doing a watch of the value. This would be the correct approach

Comment: @Code Apprentice - I updated my question with Plunkr.

Comment: @Pierre - thanks for the hint, I'll take a look at $render.

Answer (score 1):

I've sovled a similar problem, by adding the following statement:

```
$scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue){
 if($scope.innerName !== newValue){
     // now execute code
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/r9sQax4VNqBraimQi9pz

but its more of an workaround...

Comment: Yes, this was also my first thought. It would work just fine if the values were primitives. But in my case both ngModel and newValue are actually arrays of objects which might come in different order, so I have to do diff calculations to see if the arrays have the same values. These diff calculations cause noticeable performance issues when user is interacting with my directive too fast.